# Whether True or Not, it is Confusing

Tags: meaning

Please read the sentence below:

> Personal data refers to data, whether true or not, about an individual
>   who can be identified from that data; or from that data and other
>   information to which the organisation has or is likely to have access.

The "whether true or not" thing makes me quite confused. Whether true or not of what? If it is true, what it will be? And if it is not true?

Comment: Sounds like regulatory language.

Comment: It's badly phrased. _Personal data_ refers to data (whether true or not) about an individual who can be identified (1) from that data alone or (2) from that data together with other information to which the organisation has (or is likely to have) access.

Comment: True Edwin, this is from the PDPA act. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 5):

The point here is not the veracity of the information about the person, but whether that information, truth or lies, reveals the person's identity.

So, for example, it may be a widely known joke about Mr Smith that he likes to put salt on his icecream, when actually the truth is he doesn't (maybe he did it once by mistake).  Referring to *the man who likes salt on his icecream* could reveal Mr Smith's identity even though it is a personal detail that is false.

Comment: +1 Ironic, isn't it? The information, "whether true or not" while meant to clarify, instead only served to confuse, and is actually superfluous to the intent of the instruction. ;-)

Comment: @LittleEva similar to a website entitled "English Language & Usage" for  serious language scholars and etymologists, that nonetheless can only come up with a site title that invites users that do *not* fit that mould, causing constant hand-wringing and criticism of the users that *do* post there :)

Comment: @Marv Mills - being neither a scholar (or, *formal* scholar) nor an etymologist (or, *formal* etymologist) myself, I can only assume your having one at my expense. ;-)

Comment: Not at your expense @LittleEva, I merely used your highly astute comment as a springboard for my own jaundiced view on the site as a whole :)

Comment: @Marv Mills - thanks. You're right, of course, this site--being so close to ELL--attracts many "vocational" users. I, myself, come to purloin knowledge from the formally-trained scholars, and there's enough of them to keep me stimulated and "on my toes", so to speak. As we say in the States, "it's all good."

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you're asking is the function of whether or not in that sentence. It works very much like even though, even though the record is genuine or not, it's still a record, even though the data is authenticate or not, it's still data. So the personal data is a data about a person, whether or not it's correct, probably because it hasn't been cross-verified.

Comment: Hey there, Andy. "even though" is *not* equivalent to "whether or not." "whether" is a conjunction used to introduce the first of two or more alternatives and its equivalent would be “**either**” (either true or false). Whereas, "even though" (also used as a conjunction) is equivalent to **although, though; despite, in spite of the fact that**. "even though" is almost identical in meaning with plain "though" or "although"; the main difference is that even though is more emphatic, **putting stronger emphasis on the contrast between the two clauses it connects**.

Comment: True, but I thought the the user who asked the question was having difficulty understanding the meaning of the given phrase, and I think I looked a way to simplify the the phrase by changing some of the terms, "even though", in doing so, I might have given him a wrong piece of advice. Thanks for clarifying the basic difference between the various conjunctions.

Comment: You're welcome, Andy. I wasn't trying to be overly critical. Thanks for being open. :-)

Comment: You're too kind. :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there is some data in a record for a person's date of birth.

If that data can help someone identify the person, even if the date of birth is incorrect (for example, if the month and date are correct, but the year is wrong), we still call it "personal data".